# Parsing HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE

Tags: php, arrays

I came across a script that parses HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header

this script returns an ORDERED array containing the acceptable langs:

Array
(
    [it] => 1
    [ar] => 0.8
    [ja] => 0.6
    [cn] => 0.4
    [de] => 0.2
)

Now, I want to make an array containing the available languages like that:

$av_lang = array('en','fr','de','it');  (unordered array)

Then I want to loop through the first array and get the first key that is in the second array.

For example, it takes 'en' from the first array and check if present in the second array, if not, go to the next key 'ar' and check it. if none of them, return a default lang like 'en'.

Finally I want to get one of the available langs in $av_lang.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$lang = array('it' => 1, 'ar' => 0.8, 'ja' => 0.6, 'cn' => 0.4, 'de' => 0.2);
$preferred = array('en', 'ja');

$intersect = array_values(array_intersect(array_keys($lang), $preferred));

if (isset($intersect[0])) {
    echo $intersect[0]; // returns ja
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Personally I use something like this:

```
$lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
preg_match_all('/(\W|^)([a-z]{2})([^a-z]|$)/six', $lang, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$user_langs = $m[2];
```

What you are given is an array of 2-letter languages, you can then loop through them and find a language that you support, ie

```
$supported_langs = array('en', 'fr', 'de', 'it');
$user_lang = 'en'; // Default
foreach($user_langs AS $tmp){
    if(in_array($tmp, $supported_langs)){
        $user_lang = $tmp;
        break;
    }
}
```

At this point `$user_lang` will now contain the first supported language from the header (or the default)

Comment: Checked IE11 and the `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is `de-DE` for instance, therefore that regex fails. It's a shame there is no one standarized way or at least I am not aware of it.